# Typescript Pick issues

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

My simplified code block is like the following

```js
interface A {
    val: string;
    // Other optional parameters
}

function usingObject(obj: A) {
    return obj.val
}

function usingVal(val: Pick<A, 'val'>) {
    return usingObject({ val })
}
```

i am getting the following error

`Type 'Pick<A, "val">' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)`

I want a function which can accept object and other function which take each mandatory parameter as an argument

Comment: It looks like you want the second function's parameter type to be "whatever type A.val is" - you can write `A['val']` for that, `Pick` doesn't do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result type of `Pick<A, 'val'>` is essentially the same as `interface A`. In other words, `Pick<...>` [constructs a new object type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktk).

It appears that the following would work for you:

```
function usingVal(val: string) {
    return usingObject({ val })
}
```

Comment: Aha, I did not realize that, is there any way I can pick the type of one value from the interface?

Comment: Yes, write `A['val']` instead of `Pick`.

Answer (score 3):

This is because `Pick` is returning us `{ key: type }` but not just the `type`.
In this case

```
interface A {
    val: string;
}

Pick<A, 'val'>
// returns -> { val: string }
// but not -> string
```

So you are going to do

```
function usingVal({ val }: Pick<A, 'val'>) {
    return usingObject({ val })
}

or

function usingVal(val: Pick<A, 'val'>) {
    return usingObject({ val: val.val })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably we should know more about your `usingObject` implementation, but the following worked for me:

```
function usingVal(val: Pick<A, 'val'>) {
  return usingObject(val)
}
```